# Prove that $U$ is a subspace of $W$, which is a subspace of$V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be vectorspace and U be a subspace of V.

$\dim(U) < \dim(V)-1$

Prove that there exists a subspace W of V, so that U is also a subspace of W.

Is it enough to show that by $\dim(U+W)=\dim(U)+\dim(W)-dim(U \cap W)$ we can show that two subspaces can exist in V that satisfy $\dim(U+W) \leq \dim(V)$?

Furthermore $\dim(U) < \dim(W) < \dim(V)$ with $U \neq W \neq V$.

Comment: Some MathJax tips: on this site, we can write `\dim(U)` rather than `dim(U)`. The result is $\dim(U)$ and $dim(U)$ respectively. Also, if you want intersection $\cap$, rather than $\land$, use `\cap` (also `\cup` for $\cup$). Finally, if you want $\neq$, use `\neq`.

Comment: As for your question, I'm not really sure precisely what your idea actually entails, but it doesn't seem fruitful. The question asks for the existence of a subspace, which typically means that, at some point, you'll have to construct one! Inequalities involving $\dim(W)$ can only be used once you have a $W$ to work with; they cannot be used to prove $W$ exists!

Comment: Try thinking about what $\dim(U)$ and $\dim(V)$ actually mean. You can grow $U$ by adding a single extra vector, then taking the span. Will this ever produce all of $V$? Why not?

Comment: So by $\dim(U)  \leq \dim(V) -1$ we can say that U has a basis with $u_{1},...,u_{m}$ Vectors and $\dim(U)=m$ and V has a basis $v_{1},...,v_{n}$ and $\dim(V)=n$. Thus $m < n -1$ implies that we can add one vector to the basis of U and produce W while V cannot be fully produced. Your hint makes sense to me, I just wonder if this would be a good way to state it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really strange approach to the problem that suggests you're trying to figure out how to use some kind of formula from your book and find the right things to plug in in order to establish the theorem.  Even if you *could* massage this to the point that you actually wound up with a proof, it wouldn't be a particularly enlightening one.

Here is how you should be thinking about this: if you take any point x of V outside of U, then x together with U spans a space with dimension one higher than than that of U.  We said the dimension of V is higher than that, so...

Comment: Thanks, I just went in the wrong direction with this formula and kind of got lost there.